# Google test does not print PASS/FAIL. Exits abnormally

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I get this output when I run my gtest

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from Test
[ RUN      ] Test.Foo
```

and it exits after this.

My code is as follows:

```
//Exception file
class myex : public std::runtime_error {
  myex(const std::string& reason)
        : std::runtime_error(reason){
  }
}

//TestFile

class Test : public testing::Test {

public:
 MockClass mc; // Mock class inherits from Iclass
 std::unique_ptr<classToTest> obj;

 void SetUp(){
   obj = std::make_unique<classToTest>(mc);
 }

 void bar() {
  std::string error = "error";
  throw myex(error);
 }
}

TEST_F(Test, Bar) {
 EXPECT_THROW(bar(), myex); //works. Print PASS.
}

TEST_F(Test, Foo) {
 EXPECT_THROW(obj->fn(mc), myex); // doesnot work. Prints not PASS/FAIL.
}

TEST_F(Test, test1) {
 obj->fn(mc); // prints : unknown file: error: (correctly prints the reason)
}

//ClassToTest file
class classToTest {
 void fn(Iclass obj) {
   obj.some_fn();
   throw myex("Error has occurred");
 }
}
```

I do not understand why the error thrown in from classToTest is identified by gtest as

> Unknown File: error: C++ exception ...

And, why does it not show PASS/FAIl for the

> EXPECT_THROW(fn(), myex)

but weirdly exits.

Kindly let me know if I have made any mistake and also, if you need any more information. TIA.

Comment: The class and functions here are not exactly what I am using. But essentially they are the same. So the issue is not with syntax or structure of this code.

Comment: The code you provide is not identical to the one you actually used. The code here can't reproduce the error, I get the expected results for these three tests on my env. `[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test suite. [  PASSED  ] 2 tests. [  FAILED  ] Test.test1`

Comment: I have edited the code to include the mock obj. I missed that. Does that help? The code base is quite large and I cannot possibly give the entire code, but this is almost what is happening. @prehistoricpenguin

Comment: Please provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you provide doesn't even compile because of bad access modifier (everything is `private`). Nobody can realistically provide help if we're stuck guessing what you're not showing us.

Comment: The `Unknown File: error:` is common to see. Pretty much all unmet expectations say that. I don't know if you should register files somehow or is it simply a bug.